# Preventing, Avoiding, or Bypassing AppCrash

Tags: c#, crash

We get a seemingly random AppCrash, where windows actually takes over the process and closes it, giving some arcane debugging report that includes things like NTDLL.dll, StackHash, User32.dll, etc. Researching these modules and information in the reports for more than a year yields little more information that we had before. The best we've been able to do is narrow it down to a DLL our application uses to interact with a piece of hardware that communicates over TCP/IP. We have no control over this external library, must use it, and given the fact the problem is random (cannot ever duplicate on our end, solves itself on a PC restart), we seem to be stuck with it.

The problem is that our application needs to run 24/7 on an instrument that is not monitored by a human being. I need to detect when our application crashes, and issue a restart command to the entire thing. The problem is detecting an AppCrash; no exceptions are generated inside the application (the AppCrash is external to the application), and no amount of logging generates any indication the program is closing.

What we'd like to do is run a service that checks for the application running or not, and if not it issues a reboot command to restart the system. However, when the AppCrash dialog is showing, it leaves the process running.

Is there a way to either prevent these AppCrash notifications, bypass them, or set them to at least close the program first? Please, no pointers to stackhash.com or using MS error reporting; these devices are not internet-capable. We also can't fix whatever bug is in the DLL we're using (OEM supplier is uncooperative).

Comment: Is it your application that is crashing or another application that you are relying on or your application is interacting with it?

Comment: My application is the one crashing, but it's caused by something Very Bad happening in a pinvoked DLL, likely an access violation or something the OS can't recover from.

Comment: Just turn WER off, no point in showing a dialog if there's nobody there.  Ask at superuser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach might be to have the app periodically tell another service that it's alive and functioning well, rather than trying to detect when it crashes. Using IPC, you could send a heartbeat message to a monitoring service once a second.

Comment: This actually isn't a bad strategy for this case. I had considered this before but rejected it due to the case there are times when someone is at the device, and may close the software gracefully to work on it. But, I could easily send the state on program open/close to detect this situation and not do it when it's manually closed.

Comment: It seems like the best approach given your constraints. The only other solution I can think of would be to have a helper service periodically searching the list of windows for that error message window.

Comment: In the end, I think this is the method I have to go with for now.

Comment: to turn the message from Windows off which blocks the process from exiting edit the registry at HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\and set the value of Disabled to true - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You could make a wrapper application that interacts with the DLL and have your app start that wrapper as a separate process and only talk to the wrapper app (for example via MemoryMappedFile and named Mutex).
This way your app is not directly influenced when such an AppCrash happens (only the wrapper gets killed) - it can then automatically take the measures you deem necessary (for example make the dialogue go away and/or use Process.Kill to get rid of it...).

You could even make that wrapper a Windows Service for which you in turn configure an automatic reboot on failure (in MMC/Services).

Another point would be to setup the OS to reboot automatically on such an occasion (IF this is classified as a system error then you can configure such a behaviour).

**EDIT - as per comment some links to MemoryMappedFile information:**

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/06/21/net-framework-4-0-using-memory-mapped-files.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/06/06/memory-mapped-file-quirks.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx

Comment: This was my very first thought, and it could potentially provide better recovery. The problem was one of realtime nature. That DLL happens to be a very core component, and about 95% of the work is in a very tight loop continually calling that DLL. Outsourcing that to another application and adding a communication layer is too much overhead to do what we're needing it to do. This would be my favorite possible solution were it not for that snag.

Comment: I would give a try - we had something similar and I was really sceptical performance-wise but with the MemoryMappedFile in .NET 4 we didn't have much of a problem - performance is extremely high (esp. when it is not backed by a real file)... you could even put the most time-sensitive part of the processing logic directly into the wrapper and allow the wrapper to talk to your "host" app where necessary...

Comment: I have not looked much at MemoryMappedFile yet, so I'll give that a look. This would be my favorite way to go, so hopefully I can get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the additional links. I'm going to explore this some more, because I think it's the best design for long-term use. Unfortunately, I have a tight time constraint with this iteration so I'll have to go with the answer above for now. Hoping I'll have enough time to revisit this before it gets too far along.

Comment: to turn the message from Windows off which blocks the process from exiting edit the registry at `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\ ` and set the value of `Disabled` to `true` - see msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Consider the advice from:
http://forums.techguy.org/windows-7/1032392-solved-all-browsers-crashing-windows.html

In an admin console:

```
Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults: netsh winsock reset catalog
Reset IPv4 TCP/IP stack to installation defaults: netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
Reset IPv6 TCP/IP stack to installation defaults: netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log
```

This fixed the same stackhash problems I was having with firefox and chrome. It seems like a general tcp/ip resolution that may address your app's tcp/ip problems as well.

I presume these settings got out-of-wack somehow - I have pcap and other tools on my machine so perhaps they conflict? Don't know. Have you fiddled with your network stack or nic device settings?